# Splitting String Using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a little program and need to split a string with specific values inside.

I have tried multiple different ways but come up empty handed.

`[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]`

using CMD how would i return just the characters between [IDNUM] and [SNUM] to show "123456" ?

Thank you

Comment: At the command prompt, `FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=[]" %A IN ("str=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]") DO @ECHO %A`. In a batch file, use `%%A` instead of `%A`.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. `set "str=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]"` `FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A IN ("%str%") DO @ECHO %%A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume your string is in a variable - I'll call it `string`, and you want to put the value in variable `val`.

If the first and second [tags] are always as you have in your example, and no possibility of other `[` or `]` before `[SNUM]`, then

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=3" %%A in ("X%string%") do set "val=%A"
```

The leading `X` is added to ensure the correct value is extracted regardless whether the string includes any characters before `[idnum]`.

If the above can't be used because the string does not have a fixed format, then the following can be used provided that

- the value does not contain an odd number of quotes
- there are no poison characters between quotes within the original string.
- it is safe to ignore case when identifying [tags]

```
    set "val=%string:*[idnum]=%"
    set "val=%val:[snum]="&rem %
```

The first `set` becomes `set "val=123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]"`

The second `set` becomes `set "val=123456"&rem 00001[DATEC]01012020[END]`

It should be obvious how that gives the correct value.

Lastly, here is a robust solution that should always work as long as you don't run into maximum string length issues, and the [tags] are not case sensitive.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: escape \ and | characters
set "val=!string:\=\S!"
set "val=!val:|=\P!"

:: convert [idnum] and [snum] to |
set "val=!val:[idnum]=|!"
set "val=!val:[snum]=|!"

:: parse out the value. delayed expansion is toggled off so it does not corrupt any `!` that might appear within the value
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%A in ("X!val!") do (
  endlocal
  set "val=%%A"
)

:: restore any \ and |
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "val=!val:\P=|!"
set "val=!val:\S=\!"
```

If you know that the string can never contain `|` (or some other character), then it is much simpler:

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "val=!string:[idnum]=|!"
set "val=!string:[snum]=|!"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%A in ("X!val!") do (
  endlocal
  set "val=%%A"
)
```

Comment: little edit on the code worked for me `set "string=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]" ` `set "val=%string:*[idnum]=%"` `set "val=%val:[snum]="%`, perfect

Comment: @LDowling - Yes, you can simply substitute `"` for `[snum]` if and only if there are no quotes after `[snum`]. Everything after the last `"` is ignored. My original answer was missing a space after the `rem`, I fixed that error in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter/simpler (2 lines) approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "string=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]"

rem Replace ']' by '=' giving [IDNUM=123456[SNUM=00001[DATEC=01012020[END=
set "string=%string:]==%"

rem Replace '[' by '" & set "' giving " & set "IDNUM=123456" & set "SNUM=00001" & set "DATEC=01012020" & set "END=
rem and *execute* such a line inserting a 'set "X=' correction before the first '" &'
rem                           and a quote after the last '='

set "X=%string:[=" & set "%"

rem After this line each one of the variables have their corresponding values
echo IDNUM=%IDNUM%
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't look at the line format that closely, or stop to consider that the OP might want multiple values. Of course this will clear any existing `X` value. You might want to change `X` to some variable name that should never be defined, like `CD` or `ERRORLEVEL`, although that would look mighty strange. Or you could use `2>nul set "=%string:[=" & set "%"`

Comment: @dbenham: the [usual method](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429) to perform this multiple sustitution would use the same working variable: `set "string=%string:[=" & set "%"`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for a batch file

```
@echo off

set "str=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]"

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A IN ("%str%") DO @ECHO %%A

pause
```

when changing tokens to 2 you will get 123456, 4 you will get 00001 ....

Comment: well after running my script the above is correct but your answer is better for my needs. thank you @dbenham

Comment: I misunderstood your intent in your question. I thought str= was part of the string. Down vote removed.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it with a regex.

```
SET "S=[IDNUM]123456[SNUM]00001[DATEC]01012020[END]"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$null = '%S%' -match '.*\[IDNUM\](.*?)\[.*'; $Matches[1]"') DO (SET "RESULT=%%A")
ECHO RESULT is %RESULT%
```